# mutate_at using function lag but keep first row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr in R (with great joy) and want to get the differential of the columns mpg to gear in mtcars. The first row then returns NA (for obvious reason). Instead of this first row being NA I would like it to stay the original value.

I am looking for a clean and efficient way to achieve this (not using join to add the first row to the differntiated values since the code on my own dataset contains many filters and grouped variables).

my code is as follows:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(mpg:gear), funs(. - lag(., 1)))
```

I expect the first row to be mtcars[1] and the rest to be the differential

Answer (score 5):

We can specify the `default` parameter with 0, otherwise, it would be `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   mutate_at(vars(mpg:gear), list(~ . - lag(., default = 0)))
```

Or another option is `diff` with concatenating the first element

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate_at(vars(mpg:gear), list(~ c(first(.), diff(.))))
```

NOTE: The `funs` is getting deprecated.  Instead of that we are using `list`

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply. I think we are almost there. the differential would then be:    mtcars %>%
+     mutate_at(vars(mpg:gear), list(~ . - lag(., default = first(.)))) but this gives zeros on the first row and not the orignal values of the first row

Comment: @JelleJansen  Sorry didn't see that part. Fixed

Comment: sorry Akrun I added one thing to the comment, it gives zeros for the first row

Comment: @JelleJansen  If you need the first elemen as such, then specify `default` as 0 so that any number - 0 = anynumber.  I was earlier thinking about using that without the difference

Comment: Perfect @akran, library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    mutate_at(vars(mpg:gear), list(~ . - lag(., default = first(-0)))) works!